# What is the purpose of `:root` CSS selector in the index.css file of In Vite/React project?

Tags: reactjs, vite

In Vite/React project, what does the `:root` CSS selector do in the index.css file?

It is syntax I've never seen before. Usually a colon comes between a selector and a state. Why not try and target it with `.root`?

Also, is it related to some fields showing up grey in chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

The [`:root` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) represents the root element of the document, it's the same as the `html` selector except it has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) making it ideal for defining global [custom CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

*Also, is it related to some fields showing up grey in chrome dev tools?* No, those fields are overridden by properties with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).